# How to get only the content between the tags?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract the content between the tags.

Test String:

```
<target max-length="7">
   Extract this content here.
</target max-length="7">
```

Required: Extract this content here.

I've tried below but I'm getting a syntax error on tokens:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN_TEST = Pattern.compile("<target max-length=\"(\d+)\">(.*?)</target max-length=\"(\d+)\">", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Could you please point out to what is causing this error and what the right regex would be to extract just the content between the tags? The 7 in the above Test String could be a number of any length.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to at least escape the `"` within the regex string (by writing `\"`).

Comment: `.` matches everything except for line terminators (\n). Based off your test string, you have line terminators so you must account for those. Off the top of my head, maybe something like `<target max-length="(\d+)">\n\s*(.*?)\n</target max-length="(\d+)">` or perhaps `\t` instead of `\s*`.

Comment: As a side note, disregarding `Pattern` and regex, you can use an XLM parser to extract to content reliably - without having to worry about egde cases in your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the markup of your question did you escape the characters
'"' and '\' ?

I think this is what you need to say:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN_TEST = Pattern.compile("<target max-length=\"(\\d+)\">(.*?)</target max-length=\"(\\d+)\">", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting speculative answers and rather ask for clarification in the comments. Not having enough reputation to comment is no excuse.

Comment: I did escape ", \ needed to be escaped as well

Comment: Il try and phrase my answers more assertively instead of stating my opinion as a question.

Answer (score 0):

You need something more like:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN_TEST = Pattern.compile("(?sm)<target max-length=\"\\d+\">(.*?)</target max-length=\"\\d+\">");
…
Matcher m = PATTERN_TEST.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Not quite sure you want those groups around the digit. You want multiline and dotall – `(?sm)`